# Problem with eBay API Parsing XML to Google Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing, ebay-api

I am trying to call the eBay API GetMyeBaySelling I can get Act, Timestamp, Version and Build to return and write it to a Google Sheet but no matter what I try I can not get the 'Item' list to return. The Response is below and I need help getting any of the other fields. Lets say I want to loop through and return 'BuyItNowPrice' for all the returned listings. I have tried the the code below but I am getting nowhere fast.

I am more used to Excel VBA but trying to transition to Google Sheets Script.

API Response:

```
[20-09-15 19:52:46:012 BST] Logging output too large. Truncating output. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><Timestamp>2020-09-15T18:52:45.627Z</Timestamp><Ack>Success</Ack><Version>1163</Version><Build>E1163_CORE_APISELLING_19187371_R1</Build><ActiveList><ItemArray><Item><BuyItNowPrice currencyID="GBP">3.99</BuyItNowPrice><ItemID>##########</ItemID><ListingDetails><StartTime>2011-09-16T10:51:54.000Z</StartTime><ViewItemURL>https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/???????????????????????????-/############</ViewItemURL><ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/????????item=############&amp;category=51169&amp;cmd=ViewItem</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch></ListingDetails><ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration><ListingType>StoresFixedPrice</ListingType><Quantity>70</Quantity><SellingStatus><CurrentPrice currencyID="GBP">3.99</CurrentPrice></SellingStatus><ShippingDetails><ShippingServiceOptions><ShippingServiceCost currencyID="GBP">0.0</ShippingServiceCost></ShippingServiceOptions><ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType></ShippingDetails><TimeLeft>PT15H59M9S</TimeLeft><Title>????????????????????????????</Title><WatchCount>3</WatchCount><QuestionCount>3</QuestionCount><QuantityAvailable>0</QuantityAvailable><SKU>???????</SKU><PictureDetails><GalleryURL>http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/pict/???????????_5.jpg</GalleryURL></PictureDetails><NewLeadCount>3</NewLeadCount><ClassifiedAdPayPerLeadFee currencyID="GBP">0.0</ClassifiedAdPayPerLeadFee><SellerProfiles><SellerShippingProfile><ShippingProfileID>??????????</ShippingProfileID><ShippingProfileName>Flat:Royal Mail 2nd(Free),Royal Mail Tra,Same#79</ShippingProfileName></SellerShippingProfile><SellerReturnProfile><ReturnProfileID>????????????</ReturnProfileID><ReturnProfileName>Returns Accepted,Buyer,30 days#2</ReturnProfileName></SellerReturnProfile><SellerPaymentProfile><PaymentProfileID>124284320022</PaymentProfileID><PaymentProfileName>PayPal#0</PaymentProfileName></SellerPaymentProfile></SellerProfiles><HideFromSearch>true</HideFromSearch><ReasonHideFromSearch>OutOfStock</ReasonHideFromSearch><OutOfStockControl>true</OutOfStockControl></Item><Item>
```

My Code:

```
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(site, options);

  
   var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var NS = XmlService.getNamespace("urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
   
  var ack = root.getChildText('Ack', NS);
  var time = root.getChildText('Timestamp', NS);
  var version = root.getChildText('Version', NS);
  var build = root.getChildText('Build', NS);
  var shortmessage = root.getChildText('ShortMessage', NS);
   //Logger.log(shortmessage);  
  var longmessage = root.getChildText('LongMessage', NS);
   //Logger.log(longmessage);
  
  var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS);
        Logger.log(itms + '1st Log');
  for (var i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
    var item = itms[i].getChild('Item', NS).getText();
      Logger.log(item + '2nd Log');
  }

    //sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(xml);
   var LstSheet = sheet.getLastRow()+1
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 1).setValue([ack]);
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 2).setValue([time]);
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 3).setValue([version]);
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 4).setValue([build]);
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 5).setValue([shortmessage]);
   sheet.getRange(LstSheet, 6).setValue([longmessage]);
```

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE: 16-09-2020 @ 17:08hrs UK:  OK, I now have working code and it writes data to the sheet but it takes about 82 seconds to write 200 records in 4 columns. Would it be quicker to write the data to an array then add it to the sheet?  If it would be faster can you help with an example. In fact, it would be good to see how to write it to an array anyways, then to the sheet, so I can learn some more.

My working code:

```
  var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
    
    var item = itms[i].getChild('ItemID', NS).getText();
    var title = itms[i].getChild('Title', NS).getText()
    var url = itms[i].getChild('ListingDetails', NS).getChild('ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch', NS).getText()
    var imgurl = itms[i].getChild('PictureDetails', NS).getChild('GalleryURL', NS).getText()
    
    
    sheet.appendRow([item, title, url, imgurl]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `BuyItNowPrice` from `ItemArray` using Google Apps Script.
- `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(site, options);` is in "API Response:".

#### Modification points:

- I think that in the XML data in your question, `root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS)` returns `null`. In this case, it is required to be `var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();`.
- In the for loop, it is required to be `var item = itms[i].getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS).getText();`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS);
      Logger.log(itms + '1st Log');
for (var i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
  var item = itms[i].getChild('Item', NS).getText();
    Logger.log(item + '2nd Log');
}
```

To:

```
var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();
for (var i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
  var item = itms[i].getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS).getText();
  Logger.log(item);
}
```

When your XML data in "API Response:" is used, the sample script becomes as follows.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingResponse
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2020-09-15T18:52:45.627Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1163</Version>
    <Build>E1163_CORE_APISELLING_19187371_R1</Build>
    <ActiveList>
        <ItemArray>
            <Item>
                <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="GBP">3.99</BuyItNowPrice>
                <ItemID>##########</ItemID>
                <ListingDetails>
                    <StartTime>2011-09-16T10:51:54.000Z</StartTime>
                    <ViewItemURL>https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/???????????????????????????-/############</ViewItemURL>
                    <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/????????item=############&amp;category=51169&amp;cmd=ViewItem</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
                </ListingDetails>
                <ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
                <ListingType>StoresFixedPrice</ListingType>
                <Quantity>70</Quantity>
                <SellingStatus>
                    <CurrentPrice currencyID="GBP">3.99</CurrentPrice>
                </SellingStatus>
                <ShippingDetails>
                    <ShippingServiceOptions>
                        <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="GBP">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                    </ShippingServiceOptions>
                    <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
                </ShippingDetails>
                <TimeLeft>PT15H59M9S</TimeLeft>
                <Title>????????????????????????????</Title>
                <WatchCount>3</WatchCount>
                <QuestionCount>3</QuestionCount>
                <QuantityAvailable>0</QuantityAvailable>
                <SKU>???????</SKU>
                <PictureDetails>
                    <GalleryURL>http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/pict/???????????_5.jpg</GalleryURL>
                </PictureDetails>
                <NewLeadCount>3</NewLeadCount>
                <ClassifiedAdPayPerLeadFee currencyID="GBP">0.0</ClassifiedAdPayPerLeadFee>
                <SellerProfiles>
                    <SellerShippingProfile>
                        <ShippingProfileID>??????????</ShippingProfileID>
                        <ShippingProfileName>Flat:Royal Mail 2nd(Free),Royal Mail Tra,Same#79</ShippingProfileName>
                    </SellerShippingProfile>
                    <SellerReturnProfile>
                        <ReturnProfileID>????????????</ReturnProfileID>
                        <ReturnProfileName>Returns Accepted,Buyer,30 days#2</ReturnProfileName>
                    </SellerReturnProfile>
                    <SellerPaymentProfile>
                        <PaymentProfileID>124284320022</PaymentProfileID>
                        <PaymentProfileName>PayPal#0</PaymentProfileName>
                    </SellerPaymentProfile>
                </SellerProfiles>
                <HideFromSearch>true</HideFromSearch>
                <ReasonHideFromSearch>OutOfStock</ReasonHideFromSearch>
                <OutOfStockControl>true</OutOfStockControl>
            </Item>

        </ItemArray>
    </ActiveList>
</GetMyeBaySellingResponse>`;

  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var NS = XmlService.getNamespace("urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
  var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
    var item = itms[i].getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS).getText();
    Logger.log(item);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

### Added:

In your initial question, you wanted to retrieve the value of `BuyItNowPrice`. In your new question, you want to retrieve the values of `ItemID`, `Title`, `ListingDetails.ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch` and `PictureDetails.GalleryURL`. From your initial question, I didn't notice your new question.

In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high. So I would like to propose to put the values in an array and put the array to the sheet.

#### Modified script:

```
var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();
var values = itms.map(e => {
  var item = e.getChild('ItemID', NS);
  var title = e.getChild('Title', NS);
  var url = e.getChild('ListingDetails', NS).getChild('ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch', NS);
  var imgurl = e.getChild('PictureDetails', NS).getChild('GalleryURL', NS);
  return [item ? item.getText() : "", title ? title.getText() : "", url ? url.getText() : "", imgurl ? imgurl.getText() : ""];
});
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Comment: Dear Tanaike.  Thank you so, so, so much for your response, I have not applied the changes yet but I am sure it will work, I have tried so many permutations to try and get this to work its untrue.

I will be back as soon as I have tried your suggestions.

Thanks Again

Comment: Dear Tanaike.  It Works, it works, it works!  Am I right in saying getChildren are the Children of getChild or in other words. Is BuyItNowPrice the Children of ItemArray (the Child)?  Sorry for sounding so thick!

Thank you so much I can no progress further on with this.

Comment: @Razz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this XML data, all `Item` in `ItemArray` using `getChildren()` are retrieved. `BuyItNowPrice` which is the child in `Item` is retrieved with `getChild('BuyItNowPrice', NS)`.

Comment: Hi again @Tanaike Is there a chance you could offer some help regarding producing an array as mentioned in my revised original question?

Comment: @Razz About your additional new question, I added one more modified script in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks so much again @Tanaike it works to a degree. First 3 Columns receive the data but the last one does not. I looked at the script and this part `return [item ? item.getText() : ""` where the words `item ? item` appears they are not coloured in a blue where the other 3 after this are.  So it looks like an issue in the first part of this `return [item ? item.getText() : "", title ? title.getText() : "", url ? url.getText() : "", imgurl ? imgurl.getText() : ""];`.  Hope this makes sense? Also you really do not have to apologize, you have done nothing wrong! Thanks Again

Comment: @Razz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About my additional sample script for you 2nd question, when your sample XML data is used, I can confirm that the script works. In this case, the font color in the script editor is not related. So in order to correctly understand about your current issue of your 2nd question, can you provide the sample XML data? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'm glad. By the way, when you add more information, please add it to your question. Now you are posting it as an answer.

Comment: I am so so sorry. One for misusing Stack Overflow by adding an answer (new to this) and two for making a mistake. It is working perfectly the problem was on my sheet, I had added a duplicated column header so was wondering why that column was not filling with data!!!! :-(  Sorry!  Thanks again for all your help its much appreciated.

Comment: My Code has evolved into this:

Comment: My Code has evolved and I want to Calculate the below:
`var sold = e.getChild('Quantity', NS).value - e.getChild('QuantityAvailable', NS).value` The Logger returns NaN. What am I doing wrong?
I then want it written to the sheet by replacing 'qty' in this code:
`return [sku ? sku.getText() : "", availqty ? availqty.getText() : "",  qty ? qty.getText() : "",item ? item.getText() : "", title ? title.getText() : "", url ? url.getText() : "", imgurl ? imgurl.getText() : ""];` <\BR>Have a Great Weekend, Cheers